# I have to count the occurence of letters in a file with each letter having its own fork process

Tags: c, fork

Here is my code so far. It is printing out zeros for each letter. I have a loop that creates different fork child processes for each letter. Then I take the character from a file which loops until the end of a file, then it checks to see if it is a lower or upper case that matches the letters in ascii. I am really stuck and don't know where to go from here.

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv){

char characters[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
int counter[26] = { 0 };
int n = 26;
char c;
if (argc < 2) 
return 1;
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
pid_t pids[26];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pids[i] == 0) {
        c = fgetc(file);
        if (c == EOF) break;
        if (c == (i + 65) || c == (i + 97))
            counter[i]++;
        exit(0);
    } else {
        wait(NULL);


    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            printf("%c: %i\n", characters[i], cou nter[i]);
}
fclose(file);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Would it be outside of the loop?

Comment: I change my code slightly so that i call pids[i] = fork() before the if statements.

Comment: Two problems: The first is that there's no synchronization for the reading of the file inside the child process, two or more processes might (and it's very likely actually) read the same character. You can't read the file inside the child processes. Secondly, memory is not shared between processes. Each child-process will have its own separate and distinct copy of the memory.

Comment: On a more unrelated note: Don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by e.g. `65` mean the [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) encoded character `'A'` then *say* so. Although in this case you really should not to that anyway and instead use [the standard character manipulation functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_manipulation) to convert casing.

Comment: So should I have the file input information in the parent process?

Comment: Write a program which reads its input from a plain text file 
(containing letters, punctuation marks, new lines
and
digits) 
given as input (read 
the filename 
from the standard input), 
and calculates a statistic based 
on
the frequency of each letter. For each letter 
i
,
there should be a 
separate 
process 
P
i
who
is responsible 
to return the fr
equency
for that particular letter.

Comment: That is the assignment description.

Comment: Instead of posting such information in comments, edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, because each letter needs a seperate process, how should I set up my fork?

Comment: As for how to solve your problem, read the whole file into memory once, in the parent process, before you fork. Then you fork one child for each letter in the alphabet. Each child process iterates over the in-memory copy of the file and increase an internal counter for each respective character. Then lastly, to propagate that to the parent process, consider how to *return* a value from a process. Haven't you ever wondered what the number in that `exit` call means and what happens to it? Read some *manual pages* (for example for[`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html))

Comment: And for the characters, would using the tolower(c) function work?

Comment: How would I fork one child per letter?

Comment: Please remember that `EOF` does not fit in a `char`, hence `fgetc()` returns `int`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I had done that.